# Executing PL/SQL procedure from python with sys.odcinumberlist as parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

Given a PL/SQL procedure:

```
PROCEDURE MyProc(myvar IN sys.odcinumberlist, curout OUT sys_refcursor);
```

How do I execute it from python using cx_Oracle? I was trying

```
cursor.callproc('MyProc', (param, cursor_out))
```

with param being
`[1, 2, 3]` or `cursor.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [1, 2, 3])`
but it results in error 'wrong number or type of arguments'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `conn.gettype` to define the `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` object. Then use it to assign a list of values (numbers)

Sample procedure

```
create or replace procedure MyProc( myvar  IN  sys.odcinumberlist, 
                                    curout OUT sys_refcursor )
AS
BEGIN
    open curout for select * from TABLE(myvar);
END;
/
```

Python code

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('usr/pwd@//localhost:1521/DB')
cur = conn.cursor()

tableTypeObj  = conn.gettype("SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST")
params = tableTypeObj.newobject()

po_cursor_out = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)

params = tableTypeObj([1,2,3])

cur.callproc('hr.myproc', [ params, po_cursor_out])
result_cur = po_cursor_out.getvalue()

for row in result_cur:
    print(row[0])
```

Result

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with cx_Oracle 5# but lower than 5.3?

Comment: @querysoso : I'm not sure about that. I've used version `7.0.0` to test this.